# Why is Rsync is only sending an incremental file list via SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, arch-linux, rsync, openssh

I’m trying to copy clean Arch Linux installation and send it to other VPS trought SSH. It doesn’t do anything else than send out an incremental file list.

```
rsync -axH --delete -e ssh --stats -P build/ --IPADDRESS--
```

Answer (score 0):

From your message I don't really get if it's the case or no but did you type
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx or xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: as the last part of the command.
If you don't use the second one I guess this is synced locally.
You can check if you have a directory named as your IP address locally.

I'd suggest (to copy the content of build in a directory build on remote 
`rsync -axH --delete -e ssh --stats -P build/ user@IP:build/`